# How can I make this ContextMenu Items clickable and add action to items?

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-adapterview

I get some information from a database and I created an ArrayAdapter for show this information. If I click on an item a menu appears with four possible action. But I don't know how can I add action listener for this menu items.

```
     MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

     List<Client> list = db.getAllClients(); 
     final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_ID);

     final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
     listview.setAdapter(adapter);

     registerForContextMenu(listview);
}


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,   ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.listView_ID) {
    ListView lv = (ListView) v;
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    Object obj = (Object) lv.getItemAtPosition(acmi.position);

    menu.add("Call");
    menu.add("Email");
    menu.add("Edit");
    menu.add("Delete");

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `onContextItemSelected` in the same class as your `onCreateContextMenu` but you'll need to give your menu items IDs, so replace

```
menu.add("Call")
```

with something like

```
menu.add(MenuItem.NONE, CALL_ITEM_ID, MenuItem.NONE, "Call");
```

(The two `NONE`s refer to grouping and ordering of items - see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int, int, int, java.lang.CharSequence)

Then you can have

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case CALL_ITEM_ID:
        doCallStuff();
...
```

---

Alternatively, `menu.add()` returns a `MenuItem`, to which you can add an `OnMenuItemClickListener`, like this:

```
MenuItem callItem = menu.add("Call");
callItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItemOnClickListener() {
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        // do whatever you want to do... 
        doCallStuff();
        // then return true to say you've handled this
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
Create menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/pick_gallery"
        android:title="Choose from Gallery">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/pick_camera"
        android:title="Use Camera">
    </item>

</menu>
```

and

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {

        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.image_options, menu);
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
```

then

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item)
    {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.pick_camera:
            Log.i("MainActivity", "CAM Activity launching");

            break;
        case R.id.pick_gallery:
        {

        }
            break;
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

If u are not using it in fragment remove getActivity() from above.

Comment: How can I define menu items "Call", "Email", etc to this method to work?

Comment: You can add any number of items in menu xml

Comment: registerForContextMenu(listview); need to be there

Answer (score 0):

This is how we have done it..
you need to call call this method.

```
public void onButtonClickEvent(View caller)
{
registerForContextMenu(caller); 
openContextMenu(caller);
unregisterForContextMenu(caller);

}
```

you need to set the onClick property of the button to onButtonClickEvent. A long click won't trigger the context menu, since it is unregistrered right after it is shown.